Why is my AllowAnonymous api controller routing my request through authorization?
I explicitly added the [AllowAnonymous] annotation at controller level because I need this very problem to not be happening, however when I post to the controller, I get a CORS error:

Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth...&x-client-SKU=ID_NET6_0&x-client-ver=6.21.0.0' (redirected from '') from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy...

To my understanding, this definitely should not be happening (and doesn't happen on other POST actions to the same controller just by the way).
I don't understand where the problem is or how to fix it.
[AllowAnonymous]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MembersController : ControllerBase

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMemberAsync(CreateMemberViewmodel model)
    {
        if (!model.IsValid(out List<string> validationResult))
        {
            return BadRequest(new { Success = false, Errors = validationResult });
        }

        if (memberService.Exists(model, out Member _))
        {
            var failResult = new { Success = false, Errors = new List<Exception> { new("Unable to create member; member already exists.") } };
            return BadRequest(failResult);
        }

        var result = await memberService.CreateAsync(model, User);

        return Ok(new { Success = true, Values = new [] { result }});
    }

    [HttpPost("Suggest")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SuggestMembersAsync(CreateMemberViewmodel member)
    {
        var phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
        try
        {
            var phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.Parse(member.MobileTel, "ZA");
            var intlFormat = phoneNumberUtil.Format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);

            member.MobileTel = intlFormat;
        }
        catch (NumberParseException)
        {
            var result = new { Success = false, Value = $"Unable to suggest members; submitted mobileTel is invalid: '{member.MobileTel}'"};

            return BadRequest(result);
        }

        var members = await memberService.GetMembersAsync(o => o.OrderBy(x => x.Name));
        members = members.Where(x =>
            (x.Name.Trim() + " " + x.Surname.Trim()).ToLower().Contains((member.Name + " " + member.Surname).ToLower()) ||
            x.Email.ToLower().Trim().Contains(member.Email.ToLower().Trim()) ||
            x.MobileTel.Contains(member.MobileTel)
        ).ToList();

        return Ok(new { Success = true, Values = members });
    }

I've only included 2 of the POST actions on the controller for brevity.
The [HttpPost("Suggest")] action which retrieves a list of members whose PII is the same as what was submitted works, but the [HttpPost] method which saves a new member anyway, doesn't.
The javascript fetch requests to these actions are basically identical:
function getMemberSuggestions(member, containerParent) {
    fetch(`https://<api url>/api/Members/Suggest`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(member)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        ...
    })

function saveMember(member)
{
    fetch(`https://<api url>/api/Members`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(member)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.success) {
            // Redirect to the Calendar with the new member preloaded.
            location.href = `/Home/${data.values[0].id}`
        }
        else
        {
            console.error("Failed to save member.")
            data.errors.forEach(error => console.error(error))
        }
    })
}

I don't get why the "Suggest" endpoint doesn't route the request through authorization, but the unnamed endpoint does.
I've added CORS on the api project:
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SignalRPolicy",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .WithOrigins(
                            "https://localhost:5001", // Self
                            "https://localhost:5003", // Bookings Portal
                            "https://localhost:7008", // Providers Portal
                            "https://localhost:7060", // Patients Portal
                            "https://localhost:7066", // Reports Portal
                            "https://localhost:7093", // Amani Portal

                            // Live URLs go here as well
                    )
                    .AllowCredentials());
});

So what gives? How do I get around this CORS issue?

login.microsoftonline.com would have to allow CORS for your origin for this to succeed.  (The browser is sending a preflight request to that URL because it is a non-simple cross-origin request.)  If that bit needs to be a fetch, you need to use a Single-Page-Application type of flow for the auth.  Maybe see here?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/index-spa

Configure UseCors in your Startup.cs at public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env).

Yes, I have app.UseCors("SignalRPolicy") to implement the CORS policy I indicated on the question.

I don't see it in question. You have .AddPolicy("SignalRPolicy"), but not .UseCors("SignalRPolicy").
I agree with @Jalpa Panchal answer, It could help, because the order in which middleware components are added is crucial in ASP.NET Core.
CORS should be applied before authentication

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();```

Could you set the Startup.cs as shown below:
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyAllowSpecificOrigins",
                builder => builder
                    .WithOrigins(
                        "https://localhost:5001", 
                        "https://localhost:5003", 
                        "https://localhost:7008", 
                        "https://localhost:7060", 
                        "https://localhost:7066", 
                        "https://localhost:7093" 
                        // live URLs 
                    )
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });

        services.AddControllers();
        // Other services
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("MyAllowSpecificOrigins"); // Make sure to call this before UseAuthorization

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}

Controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("MyAllowSpecificOrigins")] 
public class MembersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMemberAsync(CreateMemberViewmodel model)
    {
        // Original code 
    }

    [HttpPost("Suggest")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SuggestMembersAsync(CreateMemberViewmodel member)
    {
        // Original code 
    }
}

You could refer this document for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#enable-cors-with-attributes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0
